# How to get data from tables in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TAX_CATEGORY")
public class TaxCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY", nullable = false)
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "TAX", nullable = false)
    private Double tax; 

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "PRICE", nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TAX_CATEGORY_ID")   
    private TaxCategory taxCategory;
```

Now I want to query

```
"Select p.name, p.price, t.tax from Product p, TaxCategory t join p.taxCategory.id=t.id"
```

So List it would return is
ProductName    ProductPrice  Tax

but I am not able to get this data from two tables. Single table data is working fine.

```
public interface CustomRepositoryCustom {
    public void customMethod();
}

public interface CustomRepository
    extends JpaRepository<Account, Long>, CustomRepositoryCustom { }

public class CustomRepositoryImpl implements CustomRepositoryCustom {


    public void customMethod() { 
        Query nativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select p.name, p.price, t.tax from Product p, TaxCategory t join p.taxCategory.id=t.id");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

This throws exception that object is not managed bean. If I create custom object then also it gives similar type of issues.

Comment: how are you querying ? do you use JPARepository ? if s put that code as well

Comment: added more details.

Comment: Annotate your class `CustomRepositoryImpl` with `@Service` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JPA query to get the both tables data. Here used jpa query to fetch the product. From product object, can get the taxCategory.

```
public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long>, CustomRepositoryCustom {

    Query("select product from Product as product join fetch product.taxCategory as taxCategory where taxCategory.id = :taxCategoryId")
    public Product getProductByCategory(@Param Long taxCategoryId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of query method you can directly define JPA method to find products based on category Id as.**

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ICountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Product , Long > {
List<Product> findByTaxCategory_Id(@Param Long Id);
}
```